# timeout on connecting to vsftpd on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall, vsftpd

I have a VPS running Ubuntu 14.04. I'm trying to run a FTP server on it, using VSFTPD.

I think the server is running as it should, I can connect to it locally:

```
root@my-server:~# ftp <IP>
Connected to <IP>.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
Name (<IP>:root): <USER>
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp>
```

Doing this from outside the server gives me a timeout.

```
MacBook-Pro:folder user$ ftp <IP>
ftp: Can't connect to `<IP>': Operation timed out 
ftp: Can't connect to `<IP>'
ftp>
```

I guess I need to change something on the firewall in Ubuntu, but I don't know what and how...